# Perl hashref printing keys

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have the following hashref :-

```
my $hashref = {'a'=>(1,2,3,4),
               'b'=>(5,6,7,8)};
```

then I use the following to just print the keys (i.e. 'a' and 'b') :-

```
foreach (keys %$hashref){
   print "\n".$_."\n";
}
```

This prints the following output:-

```
4

a

7

2

5
```

Trying to print the datastructure hashref using Data::Dumper gives the following output:-

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => 'b',
          'a' => 1,
          '7' => 8,
          '2' => 3,
          '5' => 6
       };
```

My question is :-

1) How to just print the correct keys i.e. 'a' and 'b'.
2) Why does the data structure look like the one in the above output and not like:-

```
$VAR1 = {
           'a' => (1,2,3,4),
           'b' => (5,6,7,8)
        };
```

Comment: You define a Hash using `%`.. `$` is used to declare scalar types..

Comment: An anonymous hashref surrounded by `{ .. }` *is* a scalar value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining the hash wrong. It interprets this:

```
'a'=>(1,2,3,4),
'b'=>(5,6,7,8)
```

as simply a list of 10 elements. (Remember that a hash can also be declared using a simple list, the `=>` operator is optional.) Instead, use square brackets to make your values into arrayref literals:

```
'a'=>[1,2,3,4],
'b'=>[5,6,7,8]
```

Which Data::Dumper should call:

```
$VAR1 = {
   'a' => [1,2,3,4],
   'b' => [5,6,7,8]
};
```

Comment: I know that but the it has been already coded that way, so I need to figure out the way to get just the keys.

Comment: That's my point, you /ARE/ getting just the keys. Those are the keys. The hash declaration gets a list of 10 elements, which it interprets as 5 keys and 5 values.

Comment: @AAB You can't get 'a' and 'b' out of there, because the hash has not been defined properly. The correct solution is to define the hash properly. There is no other solution.